# Exposing a function for testing

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mocha.js, yiewd

I'm using mocha via the command line to test a web application. There is a function that exists solely to assist unit tests and is exposed only to unit tests. This is how that is accomplished:

```
function inUnitTest() {
    return typeof window.QUnit === 'object';
}

var messagesModel = (function(){
    //functions

    var exports = {
    //exported functions
    };

    if(inUnitTest()){
        exports = $.extend({}, exports,
            {
                reset:function(){
                    messages = [];
                }
            }
        );
    }

    return exports;
}());
```

I am using Qunit for unit tests, so during tests window.QUnit is an object so `inUnitTest()` returns true and the reset function is exposed.

I've been trying to do a similar thing for my automated mocha tests. I am using yiewd which wraps Selenium webdriver. Webdriver has a function which allows you to execute arbitrary javascript. This is what I am executing:

```
yield driver.execute('window.automatedTesting = true');
```

And in the application code I have:

```
    function inAutomatedTest() {
        if(typeof window.automatedTesting === 'boolean' && window.automatedTesting) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

var messagesModel = (function(){
   //functions and exports
    if(inAutomatedTest()){
        exports = $.extend({}, exports,
            {
                reset:function(){
                    messages = [];
                }
            }
        );
    }
    return exports;
}());
```

I am running `npm test` from the command line which runs the test script in package.json. My package.json is:

```
    {
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^2.3.0",
    "chai-colors": "^1.0.0",
    "yiewd": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --harmony --timeout 0 tests/*/*.js"
  }
}
```

I.e. I am setting `window.automatedTesting = true` in the mocha test and checking this in my application code:

```
describe("Test case", function() {
before(function(done) {
    //set up code
});
describe("Given .....", function() {
    it("Then ....", function(done) {
        driver.run(function*() {
            yield driver.execute('window.automatedTesting = true');
            //the next function relies on messagesModel.reset() being called
            yield setMessagesAsZeroMessages();
            done();
        });
    });
});
});
```

However, this isn't working - `inAutomatedTest()` always returns false so `messagesModel.reset` is not exposed and cannot be called.

It's as though the `window` object in the mocha context is different to the application code's `window` object.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Is there a different, but still as simple, approach?

Comment: How are you running Mocha? How is your application code loaded and exeucted? In what context is your `'window.automatedTesting = true'`. Your question contains fragments of a [mcve], but not the [mcve] itself.

Comment: I've updated the question to add more detail